# Java encode string to UCS

Tags: java

I need to encode UTF-8 string to UCS like **'q'** to **'\u0071'** or **'龥'** to **'\u9FA5'** in Java. I have tried this code but with wrong result ...

`new String(inputString.getBytes("ISO8859_1"), "UTF-8");`

Comment: That code is pretty much guaranteed to totally mangle anything outside of 7-bit ascii.

Comment: UCS is a standar that defines multiple encodings. What encoding do you want to encode to? Or do you want to actually print the data as unicode literals like you would use in Java source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind Apache Commons, try:

`org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils#escapeJavaStyleString`

Answer (score 0):

Loop though the string and for each charAt(...) collect \u and the four digit hex value of the character.